# How do I add the JRE and JDK path?

Tags: java, variables, path

So I need help adding both the JDK and JRE path. My current path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin but the command javac in cmd doesnt work still. I have JDK and JRE 9.0.1
HELPPPP I want to add both though.

Comment: Have you installed Java with the Installer? Then the paths should be set automatically. Or do you use another Version?

Comment: What do you mean "dosn't work still"?  As in javac isn't on your path?  Or you get some error when you run it?

Comment: Like as in when I type javac it says doesnt exist. Also the paths arent set automatically cause I have JDK and JRE

Answer (score 0):

The JDK also contains the JRE, so setting the `PATH` to the bin-directory of the JDK should suffice. What exactly is happening when you try to execute `javac` on the command shell? How have you set the `PATH`-variable? Please make sure that you set the path enclosed in double quotes because the JAVA-home-path contains a space-character in your case and setting it without these quotes would lead to `C:\Program` being set to the variable and not the complete path.